# I can't connect to server(AWS Amazon EC2) using Socket.io with Phonegap on iOS device

Tags: node.js, cordova, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I uploaded a server-side code to AWS Amazon EC2 with node.js and socket.io.
When I connect to that server from browser(both on desktop and ios safari), it works with no problem.

But, when I create a cordova project and modify some of the codes to comply with cordova, get it run on ios device, it doesn't work!
I tried

```
<access origin="My-server-side-url-comes-here*"/>
```

but it didn't solve the problem.
Also, i opened up port :9000 on EC2 for TCP connection.

It seems that `socket = io.connect(serverUrl);` is causing problem..
I've been struggling to get this work for days now...
Can anyone tell me how to get socket.io work with external host, phonegap, and ios?

server side code uploaded to AWS Amazon EC2 (app.js)

```
var http = require('http');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response){
        console.log('server created');
}).listen(9000, function(){
        console.log('server running!');
});

var io = socketio.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.on('msg', function(data){
                console.log(data);
                io.sockets.emit('msg_by_server', "server got your msg:"+data);
        });

});
```

client-side code that works with desktop browsers and iPhone safari(which works fine) (index.html)

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket;
    var serverUrl = "sampleURL.compute.amazonaws.com:9000";
    window.onload = function(){
        socket = io.connect(serverUrl);
        socket.on('msg_by_server', function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    } 
    var sendMessage = function(){
    socket.emit('msg', 'msg from client');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick = 'sendMessage();'>Message Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

different client-side code used for phonegap(which doesn't work) (index.html)

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert('check1');
      var socket="";
      app.initialize();
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      function onDeviceReady() {
        alert('check2'); // shows up
        var serverUrl = "sameURL.compute.amazonaws.com:9000";       
        socket =io.connect(serverUrl);
        alert('check3'); // doesn't show up
        socket.on('connect', function(){
            socket.on('msg_by_server', function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
            socket.emit('msg', 'msg from client')
        });
        }

        var sendMessage = function(){
        alert(socket);
        socket.emit('msg', 'msg from client');
        };

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onDeviceReady();"> 
<!--
i put onload="onDeviceReady();" because 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
doesn't seem to work for some reason.. 
-->
        <button onclick = 'sendMessage();'>amessageSend</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Three things; 1- Do not use remote script on cordova applications, remember your app need to works if the device has not internet. 2- "My-server-side-url-comes-here*" is a full url path? like 'http://server.com'? if you ignores the procotol (http://) you can be problems. To, you can do tried to set origin="*", for testing. 3- Try capturing the event 'error', 'connect_error' and 'connect_timeout' and edit your post pasting the result (for more information).

Comment: wow. you solved my problem. i googled for so long for this!
I think it was the missing "http://" that caused problem!! thanks alot